# Javascript : Link two array together

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the array

```
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
var bar = [a, b, c];
```

How to link both like

```
[1: a, 2: b, 3: c]
```

By the way, no jquery please. I want pure javascript

Comment: Try to iterate over one array using `for` loop and create an object with key from one array and value from other at the same index. BTW, you should use `{ ... }` to show expected output.

Comment: the expected result is not correct

Comment: What if `foo` has duplicate values?

Comment: What if `foo` and `bar` have different lengths?

Comment: @D-reaper it actually render from Drupal API so it wont going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Return with `object` not array.Array not have a key value pair .You could use with [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiCqIiO9LnUAhWLvY8KHdY-ALoQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg&sig2=tmBP0z-9tB6LkLGdrzzr0w)

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
var bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj={}
foo.forEach(function(a,b){
obj[a] = bar[b]
})
 console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, the result needs to be an object, not an array

there are as many ways to do this as there are stars in the sky, one way is with Array reduce

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
var bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var result = foo.reduce(function(result, item, index) { 
    result[item] = bar[index]; 
    return result; 
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

if, on the other hand, the expected result is

```
[ {1:'a'}, {2:'b'}, {3:'c'} ]
```

Then you can use Array map

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
var bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var result = foo.map(function(item, index) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[item] = bar[index];
    return obj;
});
console.log(result);
```

Note: ES2015+ makes the above codes a bit simpler

```js
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
var bar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var result = foo.map((item, index) => ({[item]: bar[index]}));
console.log(result);
```